# прослушивание сокета: форма открывается только после принятия сообщения. Только одно сообщение принимается

Tags: python, android-studio, сокет, tkinter, python-2.7

делаю для себя связку приложений которое отправляет текст или ссылки с андроида на комп.
сервер на питоне 2.7.
в питоне с помощью TKinter рисуется небольшая форма, на ней frame куда будут добавляться принятые ссылки путем создания кликабельных Label, а при отправке текста он будет открываться в блокноте.
я плохо дружу с сокетами, вот что получилось:

```
import socket
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
import json
import webbrowser
from pywinauto import application

root=Tk()
port=1111

sk=socket.socket()
sk.bind(('',port))
sk.listen(1)
conn, addr = sk.accept()

frame1=Frame(root,bg="white",bd=2)
frame1.pack()

while True:
    data = conn.recv(port)
    if not data:
        break
    else:
        j=json.loads(data)
        if(j['type']=="url"):
            lbl=Label(frame1,text=u""+j['adress'],fg="blue")
            lbl.pack()
            lbl.bind("<Button-1>",openurl(j['adress']))
            webbrowser.open(j['adress'],new=2,autoraise=TRUE)
        elif(j['type']=="text"):
            app = application.Application()
            app.start('notepad')
            app.notepad.edit.TypeKeys(j['text'])
conn.close()

root.mainloop()
```

посылатель на Андроиде:

```
private class sendmsg extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String[] args){
                String er;
                try{
                    InetAddress adress=InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);
                    socket=new Socket(adress,Integer.parseInt(args[1]));

                    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

                    byte[] outMsg = args[2].getBytes("UTF8");
                    dataOutputStream.write(outMsg);
                    dataOutputStream.flush();
                    dataOutputStream.close();
                    er="success";
                    if(socket!=null && !socket.isClosed()){
                        try{
                            //socket=null;
                            socket.close();
                            dataOutputStream.close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e){

                }
                return er;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                super.onPostExecute(result);
            }
        }
```

на форме поле ввода и кнопка Отправить
есть 2 проблемы:
1. форма питона открыватся только после принятия сообщения. я так понимаю это оттого что сокет слушает в основном потоке, но не знаю как выделить в отдельный.
2. после отправки одного сообщения с телефона последующие не отправляются

Comment: Зачем Вам сокет? Это низкоуровневая конструкция, воспользуйтесь стандартами `HTTP` возьмите фреймворк `Flask` есть масса примеров, реализуете полноценный сервер.

Comment: Причем тут HTTP и веб сервер? Мне нужна программа с окном, для windows 7 .

Comment: При том, что `HTTP` это протокол передачи данных, а как вы будете данные визуализировать, в десктоп на винде или как еще - второй вопрос

Comment: и все таки вопрос был не по flask-у. если знаете подскажите по существу. как запустить цикл при этом чтобы он не блокировал форму и как постоянно принимать сообщения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

решил с помощью этого парня https://stackoverflow.com/a/17264071/9046811

```
def openurl(event, url):
    webbrowser.open(url, new=2, autoraise=TRUE)

sk=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sk.bind(('',port))
sk.listen(1)

def listenPort():
    while True:
        conn, addr = sk.accept()
        while True:
            data = conn.recv(datalen)
            if not data:
                break
            else:
                j = json.loads(data)
                if (j['type'] == "url"):
                    lbl = Label(frame1,
                                text=u"" + j['adress'],
                                fg="blue",
                                cursor="hand2")
                    lbl.pack()
                    lbl.bind("<Button-1>",lambda event,arg=j['adress']:openurl(event,arg))
                    webbrowser.open(j['adress'], new=2, autoraise=TRUE)
                elif (j['type'] == "text"):
                    app = application.Application()
                    app.start('notepad')
                    app.notepad.edit.TypeKeys(j['text'])

        conn.close()

thread.start_new_thread(listenPort,())
root.mainloop()
```

оба вопроса решились

Comment: документация рекомендует threading модуль вместо thread:  `t=threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever); t.daemon=True; t.start()`¶ `conn.recv может меньше чем datalen вернуть. Как вы разделяете json объекты в соединении не ясно. Если по строкам, то попробуйте for line in conn.makefile(): json.loads(line)`

Comment: Написал же, плохо знаю сокеты. Не знаю чем чревата маленькая длина сообщения

Comment: комментарий о коде, а не о вас. Когда у вас и других людей с похожей проблемой ошибка возникнет при разборе json при использовании этого кода, то одно из объяснений, что одного вызова `conn.recv()` не достаточно.

Comment: Какая замена возможна?

Comment: предыдущий комментарий явно пример содержит (на клиенте, разные сообщения новой строкой отделяйте).