# Проверка соединения с клиентом при обмене сокетами на python

Tags: python, сокет

Есть приложение под android и raspberry с данной программой. Программу, запускаешь, подсоединяешься, шлёшь данные с андроида. Все работает. Но если выключить приложение на смартфоне и включить, то не подсоединяется. Как я понимаю из-за "типо" активного старого соединения. Мне требуется проверять активность соединения со смартфоном? И как реализовать?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import socket
sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(1)
conn, addr = sock.accept()
print ('connected:', addr)
while True:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if data:
        print(data)
conn.close()
```

Comment: Совсем недавно занимался подобным https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/782861/202854

Comment: вероятно не хватает волшебной строчки: `sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` перед `bind()`¶ Зачем вы вообще socket, напрямую используете? (даже крошечный пример с ошибками). Посмотрите, не будет ли http в вашем случае работать.